# IN ORACLE:ORA-00923:FROM keyword not specified

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
SELECT 
CASE
  WHEN
    ( SELECT COUNT ( * ) FROM MID_CARD ) = (
    SELECT COUNT
      ( * ) 
    FROM
      MID_CARD 
    WHERE
      SYNCFLAG = 1 
      ) THEN
  TRUE ELSE FALSE 
  END AS is_equal;
```

It works in postgresql, but not in Oracle. In Oracle, I get error as:

> ORA-00923:From keyword not specified

Any suggestion please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle you need to specify FROM DUAL.  The table DUAL has 1 dummy record that allows a SELECT when there is no table to select from.

```
SELECT
CASE
  WHEN
    ( SELECT COUNT ( * ) FROM MID_CARD ) = (
    SELECT COUNT
      ( * ) 
    FROM
      MID_CARD 
    WHERE
      SYNCFLAG = 1 
      ) THEN
  TRUE ELSE FALSE 
  END AS is_equal FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code :

- in Oracle, a `SELECT` query needs a `FROM` clause; this may be `FROM DUAL` if there is no actual table to select from (this is causing the error that you are currently seeing)
- `TRUE` and `FALSE` are not recognized expressions (you would get error `"TRUE": invalid identifier`)

I think that your query could be simplified as follows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN cnt = 0 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE'
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM mid_card WHERE syncflag <> 1) x
```

Basically, this will return the string `'TRUE'` or `'FALSE'` depending on whether at least one value in `mid_card` has a record where `syncflag` is not equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I really encountered the second situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql statement is incomplete in terms of oracle syntax and semantics add from tablename after your case statement.

Each database has certain syntax and semantics on the way they are built so you cant just compare. Most standard is select with a from clause.

```
   SELECT 
  CASE
 WHEN
   ( SELECT COUNT ( * ) FROM 
    MID_CARD ) = (
  SELECT COUNT
  ( * ) 
   FROM
  MID_CARD 
   WHERE
  SYNCFLAG = 1 
  ) THEN
  'TRUE'  ELSE 'FALSE' 
    END AS is_equal from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `from dual`.  But you can simplify the query in either database:

```
select (case when count(*) = sum(case when syncflag = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
             then 'true' else 'false'
        end)
from mid_card;
```

If you do want a subquery, this is more efficient (in both databases) using `exists`:

```
select (case when exists (select 1
                          from mid_card
                          where syncflag <> 1  -- or syncflag is null
                         )
             then 'false' else 'true'
         end)
from dual;
```

Note:  I don't think Oracle recognized `true` and `false`.  I've put them in single quotes so they are strings.  More typically, I would use `1` for true and `0` for false.